# File locking for PHP

Tags: php, file, unix, curl, php-curl

The core of my app fetch content using curl and i wish to cache content that are frequently fetched.I open the file using at the end of headers in my `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` callback and will write the write the data to cache in the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback.I will then close the file at the end of the request(bytes == content_length)

`file_put_contents` is highly inefficient in the situation as demonstrated by [this thread](https://grobmeier.solutions/performance-ofnonblocking-write-to-files-via-php-21082009.html).

Now suppose 2 users want to fetch the same content(Process A  & B).Assume process A has locked the file and is writing.

1.Can process B still read from the file ? The operation should be `LOCK_EX|LOCK_SH` if i am not mistaken.

2.If processes can read or write to a same file at the same time , what happens when process B has already read all data , does it wait for process A to write to file?.

Let me know how i can improve my strategy.

P.S I am on Centos 7 OS

Comment: It's worth pointing out that that article is close to 10 years old and may not be valid today. Have you modeled it yourself to see what the numbers are?

Comment: I have not re-run the benchmark but it make sense that file_put_content will be slow since it reopens the file everytime.I am looking for the most optimum way here

Comment: In your place, I would install Redis and will not deal with files. It's fast about 50000 IOs per second and has a lot of benefits, for example: configurable expiration time for the cached objects and many others.

Comment: I am already using redis to know which files are "worth" of being cached based on a given time period and request count.On a ssd i can store more files and RAM isn't that cheap.